# How to make hover effect using Gosu library

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I want to make a box with a hover effect (to make a bold border of the box) when a mouse moves over it. What method should I use in Gosu library?

```
#green rectangle that I want to give a hover effect (to become bold border)
def draw
Gosu.draw_rect(50, 50, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::MIDDLE, mode=:default)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the draw function use the if condition for mouse over button where the parameters are the dimensions of the button, then inside the if condition draw a rectangle slightly bigger with zorder middle (make sure the green rectangle zorder is top)